# Trying to run TensorBoard for the First Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I did some research on TensorFlow today and hacked together the code below.  Basically, I'm trying to run TensorFlow from Spyder (not from the cmd line in Anaconda).  I think that's possible, right.  So, I ran the code below (select all code and hit F9 key) and it runs fine in Spyder, but when I try to view some/any results in TensorBoard, I see this.

[image]

```
# my code ...
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

from tensorboard import program
tb = program.TensorBoard()
tb.configure(argv=[None, '--logdir', 'C:/Users/ryans/']) # path to my default Spyder CLI
url = tb.launch()


# Classification with TensorFlow 2.0
cols = ['price', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons', 'lug_capacity', 'safety','output']
cars = pd.read_csv(r'C:/path_here/car_evaluation.csv', names=cols, header=None)

cars.head()

plot_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
plot_size [0] = 8
plot_size [1] = 6
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = plot_size


cars.output.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%0.05f%%', colors=['lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'orange', 'pink'], explode=(0.05, 0.05, 0.05,0.05))


price = pd.get_dummies(cars.price, prefix='price')
maint = pd.get_dummies(cars.maint, prefix='maint')

doors = pd.get_dummies(cars.doors, prefix='doors')
persons = pd.get_dummies(cars.persons, prefix='persons')

lug_capacity = pd.get_dummies(cars.lug_capacity, prefix='lug_capacity')
safety = pd.get_dummies(cars.safety, prefix='safety')

labels = pd.get_dummies(cars.output, prefix='condition')

X = pd.concat([price, maint, doors, persons, lug_capacity, safety] , axis=1)


labels.head()

y = labels.values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

#Model Training
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(15, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
output = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')(dense_layer_2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])


print(model.summary())


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)


score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print("Test Score:", score[0])
print("Test Accuracy:", score[1])


# path to dataset
# https://www.kaggle.com/elikplim/car-evaluation-data-set
# finally...not sure if I should be using TensorFlow or TensorFlow2.0
# maybe it doesn't matter...
```

Comment: Did you read this guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started)? If you need to visualize your model training/evaluation, you need to set up a `TensorBoard` callback from your model

Comment: Thanks, but I am still stuck.  I feel like I'm missing some small thing, but somehow it's a big thing, because TensorBoard still doesn't work for me.  It only reads: 'No dashboards are active for the current data set.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the TensorBoard callback as follows:

```
tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        os.path.join(args.job_dir, 'keras_tensorboard'),
        histogram_freq=1)

keras_model.fit(
        ...
        callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])

export_path = os.path.join('/tmp/', 'keras_export')
tf.keras.models.save_model(keras_model, export_path)
```

A complete example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/training/tensorflow/census/tf-keras/trainer/task.py#L129)

Make sure you run first via CLI to confirm you see something in TB, then follow same steps you are doing:

```
tensorboard --logdir='/tmp/keras_export'
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this error: Invalid Syntax 'keras_model.fit(...callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])'.  What is the ... for?

Comment: I meant ... as all your parameters...just simplify: history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

Comment: Finally got it working.  Thanks for a point in the right direction!!